# Using SymPy to generically parse and solve equations

Tags: python, sympy

I want to be able to parse string equations (that are equal to 0) and then solve them by using a dictionary of variables that I have access to.

For example:

```
s = '(x/z)-y'
eq = parse(s)
eq.solve({'x': 10, 'y': 5})
print(eq)
>>> {'z': 2}
```

Now I had written code that did something like this a month ago, but I just can't find it. I do remember however that I used SymPy and its sympify function, along with its solve function. I have checked the documentation on these functions, but I've not been able to wrap my head around how to get them to work as I want.

And an extra question:
Would it be possible to wrap the variables somehow so that I could use something more than just a letter for them?
Example: Instead of just 'x' I could have '{myvar-42}'

EDIT:

Okay I finally succeeded writing some code that did what I wanted to:

```
eq = sympify('(x/y)-z', locals={'x': 10, 'z': 5})
solution = solve(eq, dict=True)
print(solution)
>>> [{'z': 2}]
```

But my "extra" question remains.

Comment: `'myvar-42'` - just parse the string.

Comment: @alKid How? If I use sympify on a string containing brackets it will give me errors (because it thinks it is a dictionary or something). I figured out one solution though: I could do a regex replace of all {*} and replace them with letters, and then after the solving has completed, I could just place them back using a dictionary that I created while I replaced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've discovered, `sympify` converts strings into SymPy expressions.

To answer your other question, Symbol names can be anything, but `sympify` will only parse valid Python identifiers to Symbol names.  But you can do

```
>>> Symbol('{myvar-42}') + 1
{myvar-42} + 1
```

And note that valid Python idenfifiers do not have to be single letters. They can be any combination of letters, numbers, and underscores that does not start with a number, like `x_2` or `abc123`.

If you need to still do string parsing but want non-valid Python identifiers as Symbol names, probably the cleanest way would be to use normal names and substitute them in for other ones, like

```
>>> expr = sympify('x + 1')
>>> expr.subs(Symbol('x'), Symbol('{myvar-42}')
{myvar-42} + 1
```

Finally, to replace the symbols with letters, you can use the `locals` argument to sympify, as you have done, or, if you want to replace them later, use subs:

```
>>> x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
>>> expr = sympify('x/z - y')
>>> expr.subs({x: 10, y: 5})
10/z - 5
```

Comment: I believe it catches NameErrors and reruns the expression with the undefined names defined as Symbols.